# NumPy array permute columns 3D matrix with argsort

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to permute elements of columns in the matrix `A` (`3D` matrix by `axis` 0) by `2D` permutation matrix `pi` obtained from `argsort`, that contains new indices for all columns.

By application permutation matrix `pi` on the matrix `A` (`A[pi]`) I will get a `4D` matrix with new shape. For example, the shape of `A` is (2,3,4) and the shape of `A[pi]` is (2,3,3,4).

I am able to extract the required sorted matrix from `A[pi]` using the command:

```
swapaxes (diagonal(A[pi], axis1=2, axis2=1),1,2)
```

But it seems to be too complicated and slow.

**Is there another elegant solution?**

Example:

```
print(A)
[[[   73   701  2411  2414]
  [ 5515  8292  8414 16135]
  [  100  1241  2146  2931]]

 [[ 1335  1747  3418  6312]
  [ 3788  5449  5753  9738]
  [  565  3038  3800  5430]]]

pi=argsort(Norm_order(A),0)

print(pi)
[[1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0]]

print(swapaxes(diagonal(A[pi],axis1=2,axis2=1),1,2))
[[[ 1335  1747  3418  6312]
  [ 5515  8292  8414 16135]
  [  565  3038  3800  5430]]

 [[   73   701  2411  2414]
  [ 3788  5449  5753  9738]
  [  100  1241  2146  2931]]]
```

Comment: Thank's for help Willem :). I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a matter of taste, but I find the following a bit more readable:

```
i, j = np.ogrid[:3, :4]
A[pi[..., None], i, j]
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1335,  1747,  3418,  6312],
        [ 5515,  8292,  8414, 16135],
        [  565,  3038,  3800,  5430]],

       [[   73,   701,  2411,  2414],
        [ 3788,  5449,  5753,  9738],
        [  100,  1241,  2146,  2931]]])
```