# Efficient permutation of each row (or column) of a numpy array given a permutation matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, permutation

Lets assume, I have two given `ndarray`s, where the matrix `mapping` contains information, of how row of the matrix `mask` should be permuted. We may assume, that the `mapping` matrix comes from some other algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
T, K, F = 2, 3, 5
mask = np.random.randint(4, size=(T, K, F))
mapping = np.asarray([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [1, 0, 2]
])
```

The straight forward way to do this, is by applying a `for` loop:

```
out = np.empty_like(mask)
for f in range(F):
    out[:, :, f] = mask[:, mapping[f, :], f]
```

This seems to be quite efficient, so I looked at [Numpy advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and found this solution:

```
out = mask[
    np.arange(T)[:, None, None],
    mapping.T[None, :, :],
    np.arange(F)[None, None, :]
]
```

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036332/911441) to a related question suggests the use of `ogrid`:

```
ogrid = np.ogrid[:T, :1, :F]
out = mask[
    ogrid[0],
    mapping.T[None, :, :],
    ogrid[2]
]
```

It seems very uncomfortable to create all the intermediate arrays and broadcast them correctly. So what is the best way, to perform the desired reordering?

Timing information:

To provide meaningful timing information, I used some shapes, closer to my application. The random permutation is just for brevity of the example.

```
T, K, F = 1000, 3, 257
mask = np.random.randint(4, size=(T, K, F))
mapping = np.stack([list(np.random.permutation(np.arange(3))) for _ in range(F)])
```

Here are the results:

```
for loop:                 100 loops, best of 3: 8.4 ms per loop
three times broadcasting: 100 loops, best of 3: 8.37 ms per loop
ogrid:                    100 loops, best of 3: 8.33 ms per loop
swapaxis:                 100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop
transpose:                100 loops, best of 3: 2.08 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining "best" is debatable, but here's one way with [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
mask[:,mapping, np.arange(F)[:,None]].swapaxes(1,2)
```

---

Another way would be to transpose `mapping` and then use the range array for the last axis without extending to `2D`. Each row `last axis (axis=-1)` of `mapping`, decides the order of the elements along `second last axis (axis=-2)` of `mask`. So, we need that transpose on `mapping`.  In the first approach, we achieved this transposed behaviour through the latter swapping of axes. I would vouch for this one on efficiency.

Thus, we would have the implementation, like so -

```
mask[:,mapping.T, np.arange(F)]
```

Comment: I do not exactly understand, why this is faster, but I added the timings above, and both of your versions are notably faster.